# Errors while calculating time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

actual output and expected outputs are mentioned in snapshots :[Snapshot of case 1][1][Snap Shot of Case2 ][2].
I get errors while calculating time difference between start-time and end-time. The errors:

1. If start-time is greater than end-time then calculation is wrong.
2. If weekends is included and start-time is greater than end-time.

Please suggest how to resolve the errors in my code.

```js
// Wire up Date and DateTime pickers (with default values)
  $("#start").datetimepicker();
  $("#end").datetimepicker();
  $("#workday_start").timepicker({
    hour: 8
  }).val("8:00");
  $("#workday_end").timepicker({
    hour: 17
  }).val("17:00");

  // Calculate the number of hours worked
  $("#calculate").click(function() {
    // Are all fields complete?
    var allFieldsComplete = $('.data input').filter(function() {
      return $(this).val().toString().length == 0;
    }).length == 0;

    // Ensure all fields are present
    if (allFieldsComplete) {

      // Capturing the input dates
      var startDate = moment($("#start").val());
      var endDate = moment($("#end").val());
      var daysDiff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');

      // Capturing the input times
      var startTime = startDate.hours();
      var endTime = endDate.hours();
      var timeDiff;

      var operational_hr_start = new Date("1/1/0001 " + $("#workday_start").val()).getHours() + (new Date("1/1/0001 " + $("#workday_start").val()).getMinutes() / 60)
      var operational_hr_end = new Date("1/1/0001 " + $("#workday_end").val()).getHours() + (new Date("1/1/0001 " + $("#workday_end").val()).getMinutes() / 60);
      var includeWeekends = $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');

      if (startTime < operational_hr_start) {
        startTime = operational_hr_start;
      }

      if (endTime > operational_hr_end) {
        endTime = operational_hr_end;
      }
      timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
      if (daysDiff > 0) {

    var response= workingHoursBetweenDates(startDate, endDate, operational_hr_start, operational_hr_end, includeWeekends);
$("#result").val(response);
      } else if (daysDiff === 0) {
        var dayNo = startDate.day();
        if (dayNo === 0 || dayNo === 6) {
          alert('Weekend!!!');
          return;
        } else {
          if (timeDiff > 0) {
            alert('Total hours worked: ' + timeDiff);
          } else {
            alert('End time must be greater than start time!!!');
          }
        }
      } else {
        alert('End date must be greater than start date!!!');
      }
    } else {
      // One or more of the fields is undefined or empty
      alert("Please ensure all fields are completed.");
    }
  });
});

// Simple function that accepts two parameters and calculates the number of hours worked within that range
function workingHoursBetweenDates(startDate, endDate, operationalHourStart, operationalHourEnd, includeWeekends) {
  var incrementedDate = startDate;
  var daysDiff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
  var workingHrsPerDay = operationalHourEnd - operationalHourStart;
  var startHrs = startDate.hours(),
      endHrs = endDate.hours(),
      totalHoursWorked = 0;
  if (startDate.hours() < operationalHourStart) {
    startHrs = operationalHourStart;
  }
  if (endDate.hours() > operationalHourEnd) {
    endHrs = operationalHourEnd;
  }
  /*
   * The below block is to calculate the duration for the first day
   *
   */
  {
    totalHoursWorked = operationalHourEnd - startHrs;
    if (startDate.day() === 0 || startDate.day() === 6) {
      totalHoursWorked = 0;
      if (includeWeekends) {
        totalHoursWorked = operationalHourEnd - startHrs;
      }
    }
    incrementedDate = incrementedDate.add(1, 'day');
  }
  /*
   * The below if block is to calculate the duration for the last day
   *
   */
  {
    var lastDayWorkHrs = endHrs - operationalHourStart;
    totalHoursWorked = totalHoursWorked + lastDayWorkHrs;
    if (endDate.day() === 0 || endDate.day() === 6) {
      if (includeWeekends) {
        totalHoursWorked = totalHoursWorked + lastDayWorkHrs;
      } else {
        totalHoursWorked = totalHoursWorked - lastDayWorkHrs;
      }
    }
  }

  // The below for block calculates the total no. of hours excluding weekends. Excluding first and last day
  for (var i = 1; i < daysDiff; i++) {
    /*
     * Weekname mapping. There are default week
     * numbers (i.e., 0 to 6. 0 means Sunday, 1 means Monday, ... 6 means Saturday)
     * which are returned by moment library.
     *
     */
    if (incrementedDate.day() === 0 || incrementedDate.day() === 6) {
      // Do nothing
      if (includeWeekends) {
        totalHoursWorked = totalHoursWorked + workingHrsPerDay;
      }
    } else {
      totalHoursWorked = totalHoursWorked + workingHrsPerDay;
    }
    incrementedDate = incrementedDate.add(1, 'day');
  }
  return totalHoursWorked;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

      <pre>Variables</pre>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>START</th>
          <th>END</th>
          <th>WORKDAY START</th>
          <th>WORKDAY END</th>
        <th>Result</th>
          <th>INCLUDE WEEKENDS?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class='data'>
          <th><input id='start' /></th>
          <th><input id='end' /></th>
          <th><input id='workday_start' /></th>
          <th><input id='workday_end' /></th>
        <th><input id='result' value=" "/></th>
          <th><input id='include_weekends' type='checkbox' /></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <input id='calculate' type='button' value='Calculate Hours Worked' />
```

Comment: Why don't you include those js libraries in your snippet, and add some examples with input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Hai james ,i have added Cdn links of js files and snap shots of actual and expected outputs.

Comment: I have added those CDN links to your snippet to give you a working example.  There's a javascript error in the code block under `The below block is to calculate the duration for the first day` maybe you can fix that up.

Comment: Thank you James. I have fixed the error. It's running fine...